# Discovery service for {n}.base.maps.cit.api.here.com throwing an error

Tags: here-api

the previous discovery service for getting the list of available map tiles on HERE plateform no longer is available or is giving an error.
https://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/info?app_id=&app_code=

This was working perfectly last week but as of this morning, we are getting back a generic error.

I tried to dig around on the HERE website(s) but could not find any documentations about this service call being removed from service at a given date (because of the changes to the authentication with an apiKey).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the discovery service of map tiles for HERE is back in service.